# Оптимизировать код JS, добавить циклы к функциям?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, циклы, оптимизация, оптимизация-сайтов

Есть код, позволяющий воспроизводить аудио на страниц при нажатии на блок. При этом идёт проверка и все остальные аудио должны прекратить воспроизводить звук. Также если трек начинает играть, появляется картинка play, а если трек прекращает воспроизводиться, то картинка исчезает.

При увеличении количества треков код станет ну очень большой. Помогите пожалуйста оптимизировать его. Я не очень разбираюсь в JS и несколько дней ломаю голову, помогите пожалуйста.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    var myAudio2 = document.getElementById("myAudio2");
    var myAudio2 = document.getElementById("myAudio3");
    var isPlaying = false;
    var isPlaying2 = false;
    var isPlaying3 = false;

function togglePlay() {
    if (isPlaying) {
        myAudio.pause();
        myAudio2.pause();
        myAudio3.pause();
        document.getElementById("palette1").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("palette2").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("palette3").style.display = 'none';
    } 
    else {
        myAudio.play();
        myAudio2.pause();
        myAudio3.pause();
        document.getElementById("palette1").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("palette2").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("palette3").style.display = 'none';
    }
};

function togglePlay2() {
    if (isPlaying2) {
        myAudio.pause();
        myAudio2.pause();
        myAudio3.pause();
        document.getElementById("palette1").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("palette2").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("palette3").style.display = 'none';
    } 
    else {
        myAudio2.play();
        myAudio.pause();
        myAudio3.pause();
        document.getElementById("palette1").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("palette2").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("palette3").style.display = 'none';
    }
};

function togglePlay3() {
   if (isPlaying3) {
        myAudio.pause();
        myAudio2.pause();
        myAudio3.pause();
        document.getElementById("palette1").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("palette2").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("palette3").style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        myAudio3.play();
        myAudio.pause();
        myAudio2.pause();
        document.getElementById("palette1").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("palette3").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("palette2").style.display = 'none';
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Положите всё в массив да пробегайтесь по нему в цикле

Comment: @andreymal а можно с примером кода пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хотя зачем вообще хардкодить информацию в js-коде, если всё нужное можно брать прямо из html?

Данный упрощённый пример не блещет красотой (к примеру, onclick-атрибуты лучше заменить на dataset с [делегированием](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation), а также завернуть всё это в нормальный модуль), но принцип в целом демонстрирует.

Можно пойти ещё дальше и создавать элемент `<audio>` на лету, убрав его из html-кода, вытаскивая ссылку на аудио из тега `<a>`, но вопрос не об этом, так что я не стал это делать.

```js
// Единственное, что требуется хранить в js-коде — это текущее аудио,
// чтобы останавливать его. Всё остальное можно брать на лету из DOM
var currentAudio = null;


// Вызываем эту функцию, когда нужно остановить аудио
function stopAudio(rewind) {
  if (currentAudio) {
    // Ставим текущий трек на паузу
    currentAudio.pause();
    
    // Перематываем на начало, если нужно
    if (rewind) {
      currentAudio.currentTime = 0;
    }
    
    // Убираем картинку при её наличии
    var palette = document.getElementById('palette_' + currentAudio.id);
    if (palette) {
      palette.style.display = 'none';
    }

    // Очищаем переменную currentAudio, тем самым запоминая,
    // что сейчас никакой трек не играет
    currentAudio = null;
  }
}


// Пихаем в эту функцию id нужной аудиозаписи
function playAudio(audioId) {
  // Достаём нужное аудио
  var newAudio = document.getElementById(audioId);
  if (!newAudio) {
    return;
  }

// Если уже играет это же самое аудио, то ставим на паузу и всё
  if (newAudio === currentAudio) {
    stopAudio();
    return;
  }

  // Если уже играет какое-то другое аудио, останавливаем его
  // с перемоткой на начало (картинка тоже уберётся)
  stopAudio(true);

  // В глобальной переменной currentAudio запоминаем, какое именно
  // аудио сейчас запущено
  currentAudio = newAudio;
  currentAudio.play();

  // Отображаем картинку, если есть
  var palette = document.getElementById('palette_' + currentAudio.id);
  if (palette) {
    palette.style.display = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TmwU.png" alt="" /><br/>

<a href="#" class="js-audio" onclick="playAudio('fallen_down'); return false;">
  <span id="palette_fallen_down" style="display: none;">⏵</span>
  004. Fallen Down
</a><br/>
<audio loop id="fallen_down" src="https://andreymal.org/files/undertale_soundtrack/004. Fallen Down.mp3"></audio>

<a href="#" class="js-audio" onclick="playAudio('ruins'); return false;">
  <span id="palette_ruins" style="display: none;">⏵</span>
  005. Ruins
</a><br/>
<audio loop id="ruins" src="https://andreymal.org/files/undertale_soundtrack/005. Ruins.mp3"></audio>

<a href="#" class="js-audio" onclick="playAudio('home'); return false;">
  <span id="palette_home" style="display: none;">⏵</span>
  013. Home (Music Box)
</a><br/>
<audio loop id="home" src="https://andreymal.org/files/undertale_soundtrack/013. Home (Music Box).mp3"></audio>

<a href="#" class="js-audio" onclick="playAudio('nyeh'); return false;">
  <span id="palette_nyeh" style="display: none;">⏵</span>
  016. Nyeh Heh Heh!
</a><br/>
<audio loop id="nyeh" src="https://andreymal.org/files/undertale_soundtrack/016. Nyeh Heh Heh!.mp3"></audio>

<a href="#" class="js-audio" onclick="playAudio('snowy'); return false;">
  <span id="palette_snowy" style="display: none;">⏵</span>
  017. Snowy
</a><br/>
<audio loop id="snowy" src="https://andreymal.org/files/undertale_soundtrack/017. Snowy.mp3"></audio>

<a href="#" class="js-audio" onclick="playAudio('ngahhh'); return false;">
  <span id="palette_ngahhh" style="display: none;">⏵</span>
  045. NGAHHH!!
</a><br/>
<audio loop id="ngahhh" src="https://andreymal.org/files/undertale_soundtrack/045. NGAHHH!!.mp3"></audio>

<a href="#" class="js-audio" onclick="playAudio('core'); return false;">
  <span id="palette_core" style="display: none;">⏵</span>
  065. CORE
</a><br/>
<audio loop id="core" src="https://andreymal.org/files/undertale_soundtrack/065. CORE.mp3"></audio>

<a href="#" class="js-audio" onclick="playAudio('megalovania'); return false;">
  <span id="palette_megalovania" style="display: none;">⏵</span>
  100. MEGALOVANIA
</a><br/>
<audio loop id="megalovania" src="https://andreymal.org/files/undertale_soundtrack/100. MEGALOVANIA.mp3"></audio>

<button class="js-audio-stop" onclick="stopAudio(true)">Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Без картинки, но если поиграться разберешься что к чему

```js
let arrTracks = [...document.getElementsByClassName('track')];
arrTracks.forEach(el => {
  
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    el.classList.toggle('active');
    if (el.paused) {
      el.play();
    } else {
      el.pause();
    }
    arrTracks.forEach(item => {
      if (item != this) {
        if (item.classList.contains('active') && !item.paused) {
          item.classList.remove('active');
          item.pause();
        }
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.parent {
    position: relative;
}
.parent i {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
.track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: purple;
}

.track.active + i {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <div class="parent">
            <audio controls class="track" id="vid1">
                <source type="audio/mpeg" src="https://andreymal.org/files/undertale_soundtrack/013. Home (Music Box).mp3">
            </audio>
            <i>▶</i>
        </div>

        <div class="parent">
            <audio controls class="track" id="vid2">
                <source type="audio/mpeg" src="https://andreymal.org/files/undertale_soundtrack/016. Nyeh Heh Heh!.mp3">
            </audio>
            <i>▶</i>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
            <audio controls class="track" id="vid3">
                <source type="audio/mpeg" src="https://andreymal.org/files/undertale_soundtrack/100. MEGALOVANIA.mp3">
            </audio>
            <i>▶</i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: В Firefox не работает почему-то

Comment: Похоже в Firefox событие click не срабатывает

Comment: Firfox не хочет просто этот формат поддерживать

Comment: Мой собственный ответ в моём же Firefox отлично работает, например)

Comment: Ну так отлично тогда) В хроме все норм вроде

Comment: А давайте не выкидывать из поддержки целых 20% пользователей?